# 'int' object is not iterable for list of lists

Tags: python, list, iteration

I've run into an error that I can't quite explain. Here is the code:

```
board = [[1, 2, 3],[1, 2, 3],[1, 2, 3]]
col = 0
col_nums = []
for rows in board:
    col_nums += rows[col]
```

This gives 'int' object is not iterable error.
This works though:

```
for rows in board:
    print(rows[col])
```

I want to end with `col_nums = [1, 1, 1]`. It doesn't seem like I'm iterating over any integers, just `rows`, which is a list. I think it might have something to do with `+=`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write `col_nums += rows[col]` you're trying to add an `int` onto a `list`. That's a type mismatch. Try one of these alternatives.

1. Use `append` to add a single item to a list.

   ```
   for rows in board:
       col_nums.append(rows[col])
   ```
2. You can add a `list` onto another `list`.

   ```
   for rows in board:
       col_nums += [rows[col]]
   ```
3. Replace the entire loop with a call to `extend` to add all the items at once.

   ```
   col_nums.extend(rows[col] for rows in board)
   ```
4. Create the list in one fell swoop with a list comprehension.

   ```
   col_nums = [rows[col] for rows in board]
   ```

Comment: I'm surprised I didn't see that. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
board = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]

col = 0

col_nums = list(zip(*board)[col])
# [1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Wow, a cool solution, but will it have a performance problem as `zip(*board)` generated another two lists not needed?

Comment: Not knowing anything about the software system qwr is working on or how this snippet is used in it, I can't say what constitutes a problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that `rows[col]` is of type `int` whereas `col_nums` is a list. You can check that like this

```
for rows in board:
    print(type(col_nums), type(rows[col]))
```

will print

```
(<type 'list'>, <type 'int'>)
```

You can fix this problem by converting the int element to a list by surrounding that with `[]`, like this

```
col_nums += [rows[col]]
```

But, if you want to get only the first elements of all the sublists, the best and idiomatic way would be to use [`operator.itemgetter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter)

```
from operator import itemgetter
get_first_element = itemgetter(0)
col_nums = map(get_first_element, board)
```

Now, `col_nums` will be

```
[1, 1, 1]
```